# Error on updating record with Subsonic (MySql)

Tags: c#, .net, mysql, subsonic, subsonic3

I am using the following code to update a record in my table:

```
var usr = test.Data.user.SingleOrDefault(y => y.id == 1);
usr.name = "test";
usr.Save();
```

retrieving the row works perfectly but when I Save() I get a NullReferenceException breaking in the file database.cs line 412, which is the following code:

```
Constraint c = new Constraint(ConstraintType.Where, tbl.PrimaryKey.Name)
               {
                   ParameterValue = settings[tbl.PrimaryKey.Name],
                   ParameterName = tbl.PrimaryKey.Name,
                   ConstructionFragment = tbl.PrimaryKey.Name   
               };
```

tbl.PrimaryKey is null at this place, which I think may be the problem. I do have a primary key set on the id field of my table. I'm also using the latest build from the git repo on Visual studio 2010. Anyone have an idea of what could be the problem?

EDIT:

Fixed by using the answer from nosynchro in this thread:

[SubSonic 3 and MySQL, removing underscore from column name in CleanUp() method causes exceptions when using property in linq-query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2286884/subsonic-3-and-mysql-removing-underscore-from-column-name-in-cleanup-method-ca)

Hope this also get fixed in the git repo.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a new one to subsonic, I got this same error when i tried to update my data which retrieve from database to gridview. I used a piece of code which i got from this website.

Code:

```
   Emptab emp = Emptab.FetchById(txtId.Text);

   emp.Fname = txtFirstName.Text;
   emp.Mname = txtMiddleName.Text;
   .....
   emp.Save();
```

Here,  Emptab== Class for my table, (Fname,Mname)==Table's Column name

Comment: I ended up dropping subsonic. Had many bugs (at least with SQLite), troubles finding documentation, and it looks like the project is not really supported anymore. I ended up using http://system.data.sqlite.org.